# I can resolve a *.local domain, ping the IP, but I can't ping this domain

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I am trying to get **.local* domains to use the DNS server with vagrant-dns. In order for that to work I set up dnsmasq to run in front of it.

NetworkManager is installed but is set to `dns=none`

resolve.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1 #this points to dnsmasq
```

Testing resolve:

```
$ nslookup domain.local
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   domain.local
Address: 10.222.222.22
```

Dig resolves the same:

```
$ dig domain.local

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> domain.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18052
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.local.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.local.   86400   IN  A   10.222.222.22

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 29 19:18:52 CST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

That is the correct address. I can ping the ip:

```
ping 10.222.222.22
PING 10.222.222.22 (10.222.222.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.222.222.22: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.185 ms
```

But I can't ping the address:

```
$ ping domain.local
ping: domain.local: Name or service not known
```

I also tried from a browser to load the page hosted there, but I get a DNS error. The strange thing is that all other site seem to work fine, although I can't tell if it's using the localhost DNS server or not.

Using debian 8 Jessie/testing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot ping nor curl a \*.local domain but nslookup works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289930/cannot-ping-nor-curl-a-local-domain-but-nslookup-works)

Comment: _.local_ is defined as a special domain in RFC 6762 – _Multicast DNS_ in section [Multicast DNS Names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762#section-3) and **should not be used** within the standard (unicast) DNS.

Comment: Related – https://askubuntu.com/q/81797/167631

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer! So most of you will know that the /etc/hosts file will resolve domains, somewhat like a DNS server. But how does the system know to look in that file? And how does it know what order to look check that file or a DNS server?

There is a file: `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

I had the line:

```
hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

This means first check files, like /etc/hosts. Then check the system hostname. Then there is mdns4, which I believe is the protocol for finding other machines on the local network.

After mdns4 is what was holding me up. `[NOTFOUND=return]`. mdns looks for names ending in `.local`. If it can't find one, it doesn't just pass to the next and final search method `dns`, it will actually stop and tell your system that the domain does not exist. Since the domain I set up in dnsmasq was a `.local` domain, it would never get there.

So there are two ways to fix this. The first is to remove `[NOTFOUND=return]`. This is the way I chose, and it works great. There is a small delay because I think mdns sees the `.local` and attempts to look it up anyway before passing it to `dns`.

This is what my file looks like now:

```
hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal dns
```

Another option, since I don't really use mdns, is I could either remove it completely, or there was a way to tell it to use a different tld like `.alocal` instead - but I think that would effectively disable it also.

Comment: To answer why there is a difference in behaviour between _ping_ on one side and _nslookup_ and _dig_ on the other side – _ping_ uses [libc resolver](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/resolver.3.html) (which honours `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file) whereas these other tools talk directly to DNS servers listed in `/etc/resolve.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have multiple nameserver lines in `/etc/resolv.conf` and the one I want to use is on the first line.

I read the manual, it says:

> If there are multiple servers, the resolver library queries them in the order listed.

But I found it always selects the last nameserver first.

So, I reversed the lines in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Underscores are not allowed in domain names according to RFC. In my case this was a problem. `dig` and `nslookup` uses their own way resolving names and are ok with this. Ping uses system library and fails. Actually, ping fails to resolve if a part of a name begins or ends with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

In a very small sliver of use cases, (like mine: Fedora Core 31, long upgrade history), the problem was that `nss-mdns` hardcodes the path for the avahi-daemon socket to `/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket` but my `/usr/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.socket` had a different socket path specified with

```
ListenStream=/run/avahi-daemon/socket
```

And, unless you have `/var/run` symlinked to `/run` (or `/var/run/avahi-daemon` symlinked to `/run/avahi-daemon`) then it will fail to connect. I found this serendipitously while writing up a reply in the following [redhat bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1471318) and running

```
strace  -e open,openat,connect,read /usr/bin/getent hosts MY_PRINTER_NODE.local
```

while debugging and trying to prepare enough useful information for the devs/maintainers, where I noticed that it was failing to connect:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

For the curious, my `nsswitch.conf` uses the line:

```
hosts:      files mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

And I have an `/etc/mdns.allow` file with

```
.local
.local.
```

I had tried all the other approaches mentioned here and in other forums and questions, but nothing worked. After I did:

```
ln -s /run/avahi-daemon /var/run/avahi-daemon
```

the `.local` name resolution works, `ping` works, `getent` works... all without having to restart any services.

I guess changing the `ListenStream` path in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.socket` would also work, but that was the default set there at installation. I haven't decided if that's what I will have to do as a long term solution, but hopefully this will work for some other poor soul out there.