# Get ip address from .local ping into variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to get the ip address of a `.local` hostname, so I can ssh into it, seems like `host hostname.local` does not work in this scenario

`ssh me@hostname.local` does not work, so I am trying to get `ssh me@192.168.0.xxx` instead.

The command I found which will convert a `.local` hostname (not dns) to an ip address is the humble `ping` command.

Heres the results of ping

```
PING 5153F344.local (192.168.8.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.8.105: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.524 ms

--- 5153F344.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.524/0.524/0.524/0.000 ms
```

This is one of the many variants of my failing solution:

```
# Note trying not to use single quotes so I can turn all these commands into an alias:
DEV_TERM_IP="$(ping -c 1 5153F344.local) | cut -d \"(\" -f2 | cut -d \")\" -f1 | echo"
ssh "me@$DEV_TERM_IP.local"
```

Comment: Apart from your command substitution being wonky (the ending `)` should be after `-f1` and I don't know why you have `echo` in there, and the `cut` call can only use single character delimiter, so drop the literal quotes, and you get multiple lines from `ping`, so you'll get multiple lines from `cut` too), the following may also be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341093/i-can-resolve-a-local-domain-ping-the-ip-but-i-cant-ping-this-domain

Comment: It is curious that `ssh` doesn’t resolve IP addresses like `ping` does. Both use `libresolv` on my Debian system. Have you got something like `ssh: Could not resolve hostname test.local: No address associated with hostname` ?

Comment: Ack @FrédéricLoyer, I looked intro it more closely, one of the port numbers was mirrored. Its working without the ip address now

Comment: Thank @they that help me understand how to craft a better command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try

```
 DEV_TERM_IP=$(ping -c 2 localhost| awk -F '[()]' '/PING/ { print $2}')
```

where

- `-F '[()]'` tell awk to use either ( or ) as separator
- `/PING/` grep line with PING
- `{ print $2}` print second field

Comment: neat ! can be done with perl as well ```DEV_TERM_IP=$(ping -c 2 localhost|perl -nE 'if (m/PING/) {say $1 if m/\(([^)]*)/}')```

Comment: Why the ping twice?, i.e. and not `-c 1` ?